# Subclassing UIButton

Tags: object-oriented, objective-c, memory-management, constructor

I need to subclass `UIButton`, however the design of `UIButton` makes this really painful. This is because to create a button you really need to call:

```
[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]
```

So if I want to subclass I really need to do whatever it is this method does. However, it is not possible to set the buttons underlying type.

One option is to use something like decorator and subclass `UIButton` but have the actual button as an ivar and defer all property/method calls to this button. The problem here is that I then need to implement most of the `UIButton` interface (yawn).

What I have done is something a bit sneakier in my sub class. I have created this method:

```
- (id) initWithType:(UIButtonType)buttonType
{
    [super init];

    actualButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:buttonType] retain];

    memcpy(self, actualButton, sizeof(UIButton));
    self->isa = [ABDescriptorButton class];

    return self ;
}
```

I know this is pretty unorthodox, but it works and is fairly clean in terms of code. What are the pitfalls I might have with this approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to make an `initWithType:` method. Just override the `buttonWithType:` factory method.

Comment: The problem is I want to create instances of my subclass. If I override the factory method the only way I can create instances of my sub class to return is by calling initWithType on them.

Comment: Actually you are right. If I override + (UIButton *) buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)buttonType it actually returns an instance of the subclass. I assumed because the return was UIButton it would return a UIButton not the subclass. TIL that you can call [self alloc] in a factory method which will ensure that overridden classes get created with the subclass type. I guess I am not used to even being able to override static methods.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've realised the problem myself. Memory management gets very confused because we are now essentially tracking two objects that are actually the same object.